# Get rid of security message Outlook

Tags: c++, outlook

I'm writing an application that needs to access to Outlook address book, however, every time I launch it a warning message is shown saying that an application is trying to access to your adress book. I've noticed this behaviour only with the machines where no antivirus is installed. How to get rid of this message?

Here is a part of the code I use to retreive some emails related informations

```
CApplication l_application;
    l_application.CreateDispatch("Outlook.Application");
    CNameSpace l_namespace = l_application.GetNamespace(_T("MAPI"));
    CMAPIFolder l_mapiFolder = l_namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
    CItems l_items = l_mapiFolder.GetItems();
    m_mailItem = l_items.GetLast();
    m_mailItem.Save();
//Get infos (mail's size, from, to, conversation topic...)
```

CApplication, CNameSpace, CItems are generated automatically, and m_mailItem is a CMailItem object.

Comment: May be its important you show the particular code **how** you're going to access the address book. Add code, which SDK used a.s.o.

Comment: @Downvoter, what's the reason of your -1?

Comment: I told you! Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: When you don't know anything about Outlook programming you can't understand such a question! for c# and vb there's something called security manager but for c++ I didn't find a way to tell Outlook that my app is secure!

Comment: My question is NOT off-topic

Comment: That's why I told you to put the right tags and code, OK?

Comment: That's ok @πάντα ῥεῖ.

Comment: Not showing one's code is not a reason for downvoting, especially when the problem is not code related, I don't think SO obliges users to post code. Tha's the point of my comments.

Comment: If you're using C++ CLR, there **should** be s.th. like SecurityManager accessible. But your stuff looks like MFC, may be you're using the wrong tool. Your question **is** code (and SDK/Tool-Library) related IMHO.

Comment: I have had similar problems using VBA, there have been some useful suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413477/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-autoresolve-in-outlook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for a list of your options. Essentially you can either make sure an up-to-date antivirus app is installed or use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author).